# How to correclty place labels in piechart using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

tibble(
  n = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 50, 46),
  label = paste0(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 50, 46), "%")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = n)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.6, label = label),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar("y")
```

result (undesired overlaps):

[image]

desired output:

[image]

[image]

I tried `ggrepel` but result is not desired.

```
tibble(
  n = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 50, 46),
  label = paste0(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 50, 46), "%")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = n)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(x = 1.6, label = label),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar("y")
```

result (I don't know how to add lines or arrows).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `geom_label_repel()` + `arrow()` instead of `geom_text_repel()`. See more here: https://r-charts.com/part-whole/pie-chart-labels-outside-ggplot2/

Comment: This is not what I want :/